# Failed to resolve "System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding" reference from "System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, servicestack, mvvmcross, .net-standard-2.0

I am getting this error in my Xamarin.ios project.
I am using MVVMCross 5.7.0 to build a cross platform application and my core project is using .NetStandard 2.0.

In my core project I am referencing ServiceStack version 3.9.71 as this the version used in my old Webservices project.

The android application is working fine but this error only comes up while building ios project.

Any ideas please because I am not sure why only ios project has a problem and not android ?
Don't know if this is something to do with .NetStandard 2.0.

Thanks,
santosh

Answer (score 1):

> I am getting this error in my Xamarin.ios project. I am using MVVMCross 5.7.0 to build a cross platform application and my core project is using .NetStandard 2.0.
>
> In my core project I am referencing ServiceStack version 3.9.71 as this the version used in my old Webservices project.

From the error message, the old `ServiceStack` Lib is leveraging `WSHttpBinding` in iOS Platform, which is not compatible with Xamarin.

Here are a few things, you can try:

1. Update PCL and your WCF to the latest version of `ServiceStack`. If this issue was fixed, you shouldn't get any error.
2. Refer to other Library if this issue persists in the latest version.